# what does this regular expression mean in lex

Tags: regex, lex

i am studying lex and yacc from an o'reilly book and i came across a lex example which handles commands, numbers, strings and new lines, ignoring white space and comments.

I am not able to understand one particular regular expression in the example:

**\"[^\"\n]*\"**

This expression handles text in double quotes. Eg: **"test regex"** will match successfully whereas **test regex** wont match.

I read the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) article on regular expressions but i still don't get it.

Comment: [Visualized](http://strfriend.com/vis?re=%5C%22%5B%5E%5C%22%5Cn%5D*%5C%22) on _strfriend.com_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`double quote` (`\"`), `anything but double quote or linefeed` (`[^\"\n]`) 0 or more times (`*`), `double quote` (`\"`).

Comment: what is the necessity of the backslash? i mean why does the regex start with \"

Comment: It escapes double quotes, depriving it of any special meaning (like meaning double quote).

Comment: but do double quotes have a special meaning?

Comment: I think they do in lex, though it's been a while.

Comment: I imagine the regex is itself quoted in double quotes, so they escape the quotes inside to not end the string prematurely.

Comment: @haldean, I don't think so. But doublequoted string may have a meaning, which is not regex.

Comment: `The quotation mark operator (") indicates that whatever is contained between a pair of quotes is to be taken as text characters.` http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/lex/index.html - the usual thing, quoted string is taken literally

Answer (score 0):

```
\"
```

match a starting quote("). quote is escaped with \ to not break the regex string.

```
[^\"\n]*
```

match anything except quote or end of line. ^ means not, \n is a end of line,  * means match 0 times or more

```
\"
```

match last quote